# Absolute positioned button moves when clicked

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css

I have a parent div with an absolute positioned button inside it.

It is the 'Further Details' button seen on the right of the listings, here:

http://property.begbies-traynor.com/?btg_property_search_type=Commercial&s=North+West%2C+Greater+Manchester&widget-btg_property_search-4-button=Search

The current css/styling works as intended, that is until the button is actually pressed. You will notice that the button div seems to stretch to the full height of the parent div.

Am I setting up the positioning wrong? Ive tried setting the width and height of the button but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `top: 1px` setting in the `a:active` CSS class in `style.css`. Remove it and you should be fine.

Comment: Many thanks! I hadn't noticed anything overriding it, I should look more thoroughly next time!

Comment: I've actually seen issues on mobile as well with :active state hijacking the first click event like :hover does. Figured I'd note this here for the interwebs sake as removing the active state seems to have resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:absloute` add `float:right` for the `.box-3 a.btn class`